# Effective Methods of changing Shells in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, tcsh

I used to work with UNIX a couple years ago, and I am just starting to get back into it again. I was wondering if anyone could help me with a question.

For example, if I am in bash, I say `chsh --shell /bin/tcsh` after this I am prompted to enter my password. If I try to say `echo $SHELL` it will not tell me I have changed shells. It still tells me I am in bash, not C shell. So I have to exit and restart. Once I log back it, **then** it tells I am in C shell.

Is there a more effective method to change shells? One that does not require me having to log in and out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just command `tcsh` and then `echo $0`. You can't rely on `$SHELL`, see for example `man bash`.

Comment: You can rely on $SHELL, but its purpose is not to tell you which shell you are in. Its sole purpose is for you to tell other programs which shell you prefer. If a program needs to spawn a shell, it should check the value of the environment variable SHELL and use that

Comment: `$SHELL` is the "*full pathname of the current user's login shell*" (from `man bash`) which is not necessarily the current shell.

Answer (score 0):

chsh(1): change your login shell

Once you change your shell with chsh, it should automatically login to that shell every time you open a terminal.

If you want to use a different shell temporary, just run that shell directly: "tcsh", "zsh", etc..

If you want to use a particular shell for a script use shebang "#!".

Example -- The following on the first line of a shell script will ensure the script is run with sh (and you can do this for any shell available on your system):

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check your current shell by using :

```
echo $0
```

That way you will get the exact process ( your current shell ) you are running. If you print $SHELL it will return to you the default shell that will be open when you login to the server which unless that's what you need its not reliable.

```
ubuntu$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
ubuntu$ echo $0
-bash
ubuntu$ sh
\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]$ echo $0
sh
\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]$
```

Regards!

Comment: Note that `$0` is not reliable.  Although I agree this is somewhat pathological, consider: `rm -f /bin/csh; ln /bin/bash /bin/csh; csh; echo $0`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I agree with you that in certain specific cases $0 would not be reliable, but for most normal cases it is. And yes, your sample case is pathological, and if someone would really intended to, it could really mess the system in a way you have no way to know where/what you are running but in such a case it would surely mean you really lost control over your server. Better to just go ahead and reimage it. :P